# Minimum Time To Cover a Distance Without Exceeding Given Energy

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I tried to solve this question using BFS but it got stuck for many cases. I would like to have an efficient working solution for the given problem statement.

Question : given total physical energy H and total distance D. Various speeds available for travel and corresponding physical energy consumption is given. Find the minimum time that is required in order to cover total distance D making sure that total energy consumption does not exceeds H.

Following is the JAVA code which I wrote:

```
public class physicalEnergy {

    public static class nodes{
        int energy;
        int distance;
        int time;
        public nodes(int energy , int distance ,int time) {
            this.energy=energy;
            this.distance=distance;
            this.time=time;
        }
    }
    public static int getMinTime(int arr[] , HashMap<Integer,Integer> hm , int dist , int energy) {

        Arrays.sort(arr);

        Queue<nodes> q= new LinkedList<nodes>();
        for(int i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
            if(arr[i]==dist && hm.get(arr[i])<=energy) {
                return 1;
            }
            if(arr[i]<dist && hm.get(arr[i])<energy) {
                q.add(new nodes(hm.get(arr[i]),arr[i],1));
            }
        }
        while(!q.isEmpty()) {
            nodes temp= q.remove();

            for(int i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
                if(temp.distance+arr[i]==dist && temp.energy+hm.get(arr[i])<=energy) {
                    return temp.time+1;
                }
                if(temp.distance+arr[i]<dist && temp.energy+hm.get(arr[i])<energy) {
                    q.add(new nodes(temp.energy+hm.get(arr[i]),temp.distance+arr[i],temp.time+1));
                }

            }
        }
        return -1;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int arr[]= { 10,30,50,20,70}; //speed per hour
        int energy[]= {2,25,35,15,50}; //energy per hour
        int distance= 70; //total distance
        int e= 45; //total energy should not exceed this limit
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> hm= new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            hm.put(arr[i],energy[i]);
        }
        int result= getMinTime(arr,hm,distance,e);
        System.out.println(result);

    }

}
```

I am a beginner so my code might not be upto the mark but I just need an idea about how to approach such kinds of problems. Also I am thinking of approaching it in the way 0/1 Knapsack is implemented.

Comment: Something went wrong with copy-pasting there, apparently; you can click "edit" to fix any issues with your question.

Comment: @m69 fixed. Can you have a look at it now .

Comment: If this question comes from an online judge can you post a link please ?

Comment: You are using the right approach - just notice not to check equal to dist but `=>` cause you may exceed  the distance and do not just return the `temp.time+1` but save min value of all those option and in the end return the minimum

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the value of Breadth First search to achieve "an efficient working solution", where you could use a simple one loop solution :

```
//returned value is not necessarily int
public static double getMinTime(HashMap<Integer,Integer> speedEnerhgyMap
                                          , int dist , int energyLimit) {

    List<Integer> speeds = new ArrayList<>(speedEnerhgyMap.keySet());
    Collections.sort(speeds, Collections.reverseOrder()); //highest speed first

    //iterate starting at highest speed = shortest time
    for(int speed : speeds) {
        double time = (double)dist / speed; //code verbose to make it clear
        double energyUsed =  time * speedEnerhgyMap.get(speed);
        if(energyUsed <= energyLimit) {
            return time;
        }
    }

    return Double.NaN;
}
```

Test it with the `hm` map.